# Which method of wireless tether uses the least amount of power? Bluetooth or Wifi?

Tags: bluetooth, battery-life, tethering, wifi-tethering

If I'm going to wireless tehter to my Android phone what method drains the battery the least? Wifi or Bluetooth?

Comment: I'd guess Bluetooth, as Bluetooth has lower transmission range (and thusly should use less power, at least theoretically), but I have no hard data about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I decided to look up some data, and my guess seems to be correct: http://nesl.ee.ucla.edu/fw/documents/reports/2007/PowerAnalysis.pdf

According to the report, Bluetooth takes the least amount of energy.

However your 3G radio will probably take the most energy; maintaining a 3G connection without transferring any data is cheap, but once you start sending/receiving data, then it trumps even Wi-fi.

> WiFi radios have a high wakeup and
>   connection maintenance energy, but low
>   energy per bit transmission cost and
>   high bandwidth.
>
> Cellular radios have low connection
>   maintenance energy, but high energy
>   per bit transmission cost and low
>   bandwidth.

Disclaimer: The study might only apply for the particular model that the device they use.